# How do I remove all characters in a string until a substring is matched, in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, regex, string

Say I have a string: `Hey what's up @dude, @how's it going?`

I'd like to remove *all* the characters before`@how's`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

or with the regex:

```
str = "Hey what's up @dude, @how's it going?"
str.gsub!(/.*?(?=@how)/im, "") #=> "@how's it going?"
```

you can read about lookaround at [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

Comment: Considering that it could be in any case variation of @how (e.g. @How, @HOW, @HoW etc), could it be done like this: str.gsub(/.*?(?=@[Hh][Oo][Ww])/, "")?

Comment: sure, fixed. (/i have been added)

Comment: No need for `gsub!` when `sub!` will do, right? Also note (per my answer) that you need the `\A` anchor and/or `m` flag in case the string has a newline before the text to match.

Comment: Thanks! Sorry, I don't know the difference between gsub and sub. Could you explain it?

Comment: Suuuuper old and you obviously probably know the difference by now, but would be nice to see the answer changed for n00bs: gsub does a global search and replace while sub stops after the first match.  gsub could cause unexpected results or poor performance is longer strings.

Answer (score 15):

Use [String#slice](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M001213)

```
s = "Hey what's up @dude, @how's it going?"
s.slice(s.index("@how")..-1)
# => "@how's it going?"
```

Comment: +1 very clean. Aren't the indices off though? Shouldn't it be `0..s.index("@how")`?

Comment: He wants to strip everything before the match, that is the same to say "keep everything after the match".

Comment: Oh whoops, I misunderstood how splice worked. I thought it removed the string in place, like a delete method. I didn't realize it returned the spliced text for use.

Comment: I commented below to another answer, but I was wondering that since it could be in any case variation of @how (e.g. @How, @HOW, @HoW etc), could it be done like this: str.slice(str.index("@[Hh][Oo][Ww]")..-1)

Comment: If the search string doesn't appear, the `index` will return `nil`. So he should either check for `nil` before doing the `slice`, or plan to rescue the error that comes from passing an index of `nil` to `slice`.

Answer (score 8):

There are literally tens of ways of doing this. Here are the ones I would use:

If you want to **preserve the original string**:

```
str = "Hey what's up @dude, @how's it going?"
str2 = str[/@how's.+/mi]
p str, str2
#=> "Hey what's up @dude, @how's it going?"
#=> "@how's it going?"
```

If you want to **mutate the original string**:

```
str = "Hey what's up @dude, @how's it going?"
str[/\A.+?(?=@how's)/mi] = ''
p str
#=> "@how's it going?"
```

...or...

```
str = "Hey what's up @dude, @how's it going?"
str.sub! /\A.+?(?=@how's)/mi, ''
p str
#=> "@how's it going?"
```

You need the `\A` to anchor at the start of the string, and the `m` flag to ensure that you are matching across multiple lines.

Perhaps simplest of all for mutating the original:

```
str = "Hey what's up @dude, @how's it going?"
str.replace str[/@how's.+/mi]
p str
#=> "@how's it going?"
```

Answer (score 2):

[`String#slice`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/String.html#method-i-slice) and [`String#index`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/String.html#method-i-index) work fine but will blow up with *ArgumentError: bad value for range* if the needle is not in the haystack.

Using [`String#partition`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/String.html#method-i-partition) or [`String#rpartition`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/String.html#method-i-rpartition) might work better in that case:

```
s.partition "@how's"
# => ["Hey what's up @dude, ", "@how's", " it going?"]
s.partition "not there"
# => ["Hey what's up @dude, @how's it going?", "", ""]
s.rpartition "not there"
# => ["", "", "Hey what's up @dude, @how's it going?"]
```

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to get only the part you are interested in.

```
>> s="Hey what's up @dude, @how's it going?"
=> "Hey what's up @dude, @how's it going?"
>> s[/@how.*$/i]
=> "@how's it going?"
```

If you really need to change the string object, you could always do `s=s[...]`.

Answer (score 0):

```
>> "Hey what's up @dude, @how's it going?".partition("@how's")[-2..-1].join
=> "@how's it going?"
```

Case insensitive

```
>> "Hey what's up @dude, @HoW's it going?".partition(/@how's/i)[-2..-1].join
=> "@HoW's it going?"
```

Or using `scan()`

```
>> "Hey what's up @dude, @HoW's it going?".scan(/@how's.*/i)[0]
=> "@HoW's it going?"
```

Comment: You need a `m` flag on that last regex to match any newlines that may follow.

Answer (score 0):

You can also directly call `[]` also on a string(same as `slice`)

```
s = "Hey what's up @dude, @how's it going?"
start_index = s.downcase.index("@how")
start_index ? s[start_index..-1] : ""
```