# Get XML from a string

Tags: c#, regex, windows-phone-7.1

I have a Socket communication in my Windows Phone app, but when I call it I can sometimes get a result, that looks like this

```
\0\0\0\0<RESULT><DATA>...</DATA></RESULT>\0
```

I want to remove the start and the end of it so I only get the XML, but what is the best way to do it? 
I have thought about Regex, but I can not make it work :(

Comment: What are you talking to? It sounds like quite possibly you've got the protocol slightly wrong.

Comment: You could use `string xml = ReturnString.Trim('\0');` I guess.

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal I have tried many things, but right now I am trying with 2 regexes, where they are almost equal and looks like this Regex.Replace(DataFromServer, "^.*?<", "<");

Comment: @JonSkeet The communication is working right, after I added header and the end-byte to the message

Comment: @yogi That is tried, but I do not work in the start, as there is some other letters, I can not copy-paste here (I do not know why, but Visual Studio shows them as question marks)

Comment: Are you somehow misinterpreting a byte-order-mark (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1772321/what-is-xml-bom-and-how-do-i-detect-it) ?

Comment: @yogi My Socket looks like this 

   new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

Comment: @BrianAgnew It could be, but how do I remove it?

Comment: [This early question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5501284/how-do-i-remove-all-characters-in-a-string-until-a-substring-is-matched-in-ruby) might be useful.

Comment: @The87Boy: If you're garbage at the start and end of the message, I don't think you *do* have the communication working correctly. Please add more information in your question.

Comment: @JonSkeet I found out of that my client was receiving the reciept, then the total amount of bytes, then the body and at the end a end-byte, so it was integrated correct, but I could not figure out the reciept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not enough information to answer you correctly, so I will suggest the following :

You should try to map the data you are receiving from your socket to a serializable class. 
And then you serialize the classObject to an XML document.

```
public class socketDataToMap
{
    public string Data {get; set;}
}
```

and then

```
var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(socketDataToMap));
using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(yourSocketStream))
            {
                var deserializedObject = ser.Deserialize(reader) as socketDataToMap;

            }
```

and then you serialize to an XML file. I see something like this for your problem.

Comment: I can not make this work, as Windows Phone only support asyncrhonous socket-communication

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like a problem with your protocol, but to remove the \0 characters you could do a simple trimming of the string.

If your string has the actual \ and 0 characters in it then you could do the following:

```
var fixedData = receivedData.Trim(new[] { '\\', '0' });
```

And if the string starts with null characters (encoded as \0) then you could to:

```
var fixedData = receivedData.Trim(new[] { '\0' });
```

Both examples assume that the variable receviedData is a String containing your data.

Comment: This does not remove all the characters :(

Comment: If you have more characters than the ones in your example code then you must add them as well in the call to .Trim.

Answer (score 0):

If your result have to be `XML` and more characters(else `\0`) can be in start or end of your string, these code can be useful:

```
var start = inputString.IndexOf('<');
var end = inputString.LastIndexOf('>');
var result = inputString.Substring(start, end - start);
```

- [`String.IndexOf Method (Char)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwb0bwyd): Reports the zero-based index of the first occurrence of the specified Unicode character in this string.
- [`String.LastIndexOf Method (Char)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w96zd3d): Reports the zero-based index position of the last occurrence of a specified Unicode character within this instance.
- [`String.Substring Method (Int32, Int32)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs): Retrieves a substring from this instance. The substring starts at a specified character position and has a specified length.